# PATH, bash, profile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I know. Yet another question about the very basics of Linux, but I obviously am missing some tidbit here despite reading many threads about this subject. I recently had to nuke-and-pave (and reinstall 10+ apps), so I am a bit flinchy about hacking on something so basic as the PATH, lest I have a machine that goes brain-dead...

System information: **Linux Mint 21.1 'Cinnamon', 64-bit**.

**Statement of problem:** I need to update my PATH. I know how to do this with the 'export' command but that's a temporary change, so it's essentially useless. Lots of talk in various threads about the **~/.profile** and **bash** and **bashrc** files, but I could not find anything quite like that until I resorted to brute-force search of the entire file structure; I then found at **[root}/usr/share/base-files** these files:

```
/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
/usr/share/base-files/dot.profile
/usr/share/base-files/dot.profile.md5sums
/usr/share/base-files/info.dir
/usr/share/base-files/motd
/usr/share/base-files/networks
/usr/share/base-files/profile
/usr/share/base-files/profile.md5sums
/usr/share/base-files/staff-group-for-usr-local
```

and of these only the file **~/dot.profile** corresponds with prior-thread descriptions of the required file to alter. The full file content is....

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Now, to me, it is disconcerting that the word **PATH** does not occur anywhere in the ~/dot.profle file. So I am leery about altering it. Unlike Putin, I have no interest in spending three more days nuking-and-paving.

If somebody would:

1. Confirm that this is **the correct file to alter**; and
2. Suggest the **additional lines required** to set $PATH to include my new applications...

that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the question title "describe your question or problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about"  : Ref: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/289691)

Comment: An easy way to add to $PATH is giving command `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/your/new/path"' >> /home/YourUser/.profile`. Then `source ~/.profile` and the new path is activated. Or you can put the export in `~/.bashrc` and source that to activate. Neither of these will bork your system. To be certain, just `cp ~/.profile ~/.profile_orig` before adding the path, and the original file is saved and can be restored just with reverse copy and sourcing again. Add'l lines can't be suggested without info on what the new apps are - usually no additions are needed, if yes they'll be in the instructions.

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bashrc-vs-bash-profile-vs-profile) on the differences of where variables are loaded.  Export is NOT TEMPORARY when anything that launches invokes it and anything launched from that inherits the environment (by default).  Please look at @Peregrino69 comment.  There is a lot left to learn but his suggestion is a good start.

Comment: I tried the suggestion of 'Peregrino69' and (!!!) it works. I have copied this into a file that I have written about these issues---thanks very much.

Comment: OK, so now "the penny finally drops" and I know why I have had so much trouble with the suggestions I have been reading prior to this----- I had "view hidden files" turned OFF in the GUI, and had NOT issued the  $ls -a command in the terminal environment. So...of course....I was not seeing any of the files .profile  or  .bashrc

Comment: With the "show hidden files" turned on, easy to find in the GUI and confirm that ...yes indeed, the .profile contains the precise PATH change required. thanks once again.... :-)

Comment: @Bridman There is no reason to basically post the same question twice. Especially as i gave you an answer on the first question, and you simply did not respond.

Comment: _Your_ question from earlier. [Linux Mint $PATH, environment global change](https://superuser.com/questions/1769795/linux-mint-path-environment-global-change)

Comment: Malik--see comment on prior question (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/usr/share/base-files/dot.profile` to `~/.profile` and then append the line

```
PATH=${PATH}:/dir/to/be/added
```

as the last line of the file. Source the profile using `. ~/.profile` to confirm it works. You'll then get the new PATH from now own. FYI, I have never seen a Linux system that did not install the dot files when creating a new user. Something seems off in your system.

Comment: `. ./.profile` instead of `. ~/.profile` implies his current working directory is $HOME? No?  Yes, never seen dot.profile missing but never used it.  Not important.

Comment: See comment above. Not enough recent experience with terminal and, generally, with Linux. D'Oh.